# Rebuild a binary tree from preorder and inorder lists

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree, inorder, preorder

Hi I'm trying to rebuild a binary tree, I almost got it, except it throws me an error and I don't know why

```
buildTree :: (Ord a, Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Tree a
buildTree [] [] = Empty
buildTree preOrd inOrd = Node root left right 
where root  = head preOrd
      left = buildTree leftPreOrd leftInOrd
      right = buildTree rigthPreOrd leftInOrd

      Just rootInd = elemIndex root inOrd
      leftPreOrd   = tail (take (rootInd + 1) preOrd)
      rigthPreOrd  = tail (drop rootInd preOrd)

      leftInOrd    = take rootInd inOrd
      rightInord   = drop (rootInd + 1) inOrd
```

When I call it using

```
buildTree [10,5,2,6,14,12,15] [2,5,6,10,12,14,15]
```

it throws me this:

```
Exception: reconstruir.hs:26:11-45: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern Just rootInd
```

Comment: You are passing `leftInOrd`, not `rightInOrd`, to the call to `buildTree` that computes the right subtree.

Answer (score 2):

The runtime is failing on this line:

```
Just rootInd = elemIndex root inOrd
```

`elemIndex` is returning `Nothing` when running your example input, but your code says it will always return a `Just`, so the runtime crashes. You need to handle the case where `elemIndex root inOrd` returns `Nothing`.

Perhaps more importantly, you should enable all warnings with the [`-Wall` flag](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html) to show up as compiler errors so that your code wouldn't compile to begin with.

Comment: Assuming the inputs are valid traversals of the same tree, one should be able to prove that `elemIndex` *won't* return `Nothing`. I believe it is a typo in the code that allows that case.

Comment: That's a big assumption, though. I think it's better to have this function return `Maybe (Tree a)` to allow for the case that it gets incorrect inputs.

Answer (score 1):

@chepner has spotted the error.  If you'd like to know how to find and fix these sorts of errors yourself in the future, you may find the following answer helpful...

First, it helps to find the smallest test case possible.  With a few tries, it's not hard to get your program to fail on a 2-node tree:

```
> buildTree [5,2] [2,5]
Node 5 (Node 2 Empty Empty) (Node *** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Now, try tracing the evaluation of `buildTree [5,2] [2,5]` by hand.  If you evaluate this first `buildTree` call manually, you'll find the variables involved have values:

```
preOrd = [5,2]
inOrd = [2,5]
Just rootInd = Just 1

leftPreord = tail (take 2 [5,2]) = [2]
rightPreord = tail (drop 1 [5,2]) = []

leftInOrd = take 1 [2,5] = [2]
rigthInord = drop 2 [2,5] = []

root = 5
left = buildTree [2] [2]
right = buildTree [] [2]
```

Everything looks fine, except `right`, which tries to build a tree with incompatible preorder and inorder lists.  That's what causes the error, since `buildTree [] [2]` tries to take the `head` of an empty list.  (The error message is a little different for your test case, but the underlying cause is the same.)

This pinpoints the problem as the second argument to `buildTree` in the definition of `right` -- the value `2` shouldn't be included in the (empty) right tree.  From there, it's easy to spot and fix the typo in the definition of `right` so it reads:

```
read = buildTree rigthPreOrd rightInOrd
```

After that fix, things seem to work okay.